Why Does My TTT Engine with MCTS Perform Better Using Highest UCB Score (c=0) Over Highest Evaluation for Best Moves?
I’m currently implementing a Tic-Tac-Toe (TTT) engine using Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS). However, I’ve encountered an issue with the function responsible for calculating the best moves. Initially, I chose the child node with the highest evaluation score, but this approach failed to block the opponent’s winning moves. On the other hand, when I used the highest Upper Confidence Bound (UCB) score with c = 0 , the AI performed perfectly. Can someone explain why the UCB score method works better in this scenario, or is it just a bug in my implementation?
I've included a MCVE below (the relevant part is in Node::CalculateBestMove):
main.cc
#include "node.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <deque>

#define DEBUG 0

void print_board(uint16_t ai_board, uint16_t enemy_board, char ai, char player) {
  char board[9] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (ai_board & (1 << i))
      board[i] = ai;
    else if (enemy_board & (1 << i))
      board[i] = player;
  }

  std::cout << " A   B   C\n\n";
  std::cout << " " << board[0] << " | " << board[1] << " | " << board[2] << "   1\n";
  std::cout << "---|---|---\n";
  std::cout << " " << board[3] << " | " << board[4] << " | " << board[5] << "   2\n";
  std::cout << "---|---|---\n";
  std::cout << " " << board[6] << " | " << board[7] << " | " << board[8] << "   3\n";
}

bool is_valid_coordinate(char col, char row) {
  return (col >= 'A' && col <= 'C') && (row >= '1' && row <= '3');
}

int coordinate_to_idx(char col, char row) {
  return (col - 'A') + 3 * (row - '1');
}

#if DEBUG
size_t get_node_count(Node *root) {
  size_t c = 1;

  for(int i = 0; i < root->child_count; i++) {
    c += get_node_count(root->children[i]);
  }

  return c;
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char player;

  for(;;) {
    std::string selection;
    std::cout << "Select your symbol (X/O): ";
    std::cin >> selection;

    if(selection.length() != 1) {
      std::cout << "Invalid input format. Try again.\n";
      continue;
    }
    player = std::toupper(selection[0]);

    if(player != 'X' && player != 'O') {
      std::cout << "Invalid selection. Try again.\n";
      continue;
    }

    break;
  }

  char ai = player == 'O' ? 'X' : 'O';
  bool is_ai_turn = ai == 'X';

  std::deque<Node> arena;
  Node root(&arena, is_ai_turn);
  Node *curr_node = &root;

  if(!is_ai_turn)
    print_board(0, 0, ai, player);

  while (true) {
    if (curr_node->GetWinner()) {
      std::cout << "Game Over! ";
      if (curr_node->GetWinner() == 1)
        std::cout << "AI wins!\n";
      else
        std::cout << "You win!\n";
      break;
    }
    else if((curr_node->ai_board | curr_node->enemy_board) == 0b111111111) {
      std::cout << "Game Over! Tie!\n";
      break;
    }

    if (curr_node->is_ai_turn) {
      curr_node = curr_node->CalculateBestMove(1000);
      std::cout << "AI's move:\n";
      print_board(curr_node->ai_board, curr_node->enemy_board, ai, player);
    } 
    else {
      std::cout << "Enter your move (e.g., A1, B2): ";
      std::string move;
      std::cin >> move;

      if (move.size() != 2) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input format. Try again.\n";
        continue;
      }

      char col = std::toupper(move[0]);
      char row = move[1];

      if (!std::isalpha(col) || !std::isdigit(row) || !is_valid_coordinate(col, row)) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input format. Try again.\n";
        continue;
      }

      int idx = coordinate_to_idx(col, row);

      if (curr_node->ai_board & (1 << idx) || curr_node->enemy_board & (1 << idx)) {
        std::cout << "The position is already taken. Try again.\n";
        continue;
      }

      curr_node = curr_node->SearchEnemyMove(idx);

      assert(curr_node != nullptr);
      std::cout << "Your move:\n";
      print_board(curr_node->ai_board, curr_node->enemy_board, ai, player);
    }
#if DEBUG
    std::cout << "Amount of nodes in tree: " << get_node_count(&root) << '\n';
#endif
  }

  return 0;
}

node.hpp
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <deque>

struct Node {
  int64_t eval;
  size_t visit_count;
  Node *parent;
  uint16_t ai_board;
  uint16_t enemy_board;
  uint8_t child_count;
  Node *children[9];
  std::deque<Node>* arena;
  bool is_ai_turn;

  Node(std::deque<Node> *arena, bool is_ai_turn);
  Node *CalculateBestMove(size_t iter_count);
  Node *SearchEnemyMove(int move);
  int GetWinner();

private:
  Node *GetBestChild(double c);
  Node *FindBestLeafNode();
  void CreateChildren();
  void SimulateAndBackpropagate();
  double GetUcbScore(double c);
};
#endif // NODE_HPP 

node.cc
#include "node.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

Node::Node(std::deque<Node> *arena, bool is_ai_turn) {
  this->eval = 0;
  this->visit_count = 0;
  this->parent = nullptr;
  this->ai_board = 0;
  this->enemy_board = 0;
  this->child_count = 0;
  this->arena = arena;
  this->is_ai_turn = is_ai_turn;
}

Node *Node::GetBestChild(double c) {
  double best_score = -DBL_MAX;
  Node* best_child = nullptr;
  assert(this->child_count > 0);

  for (auto i = 0; i < this->child_count; i++) {
    auto score = this->children[i]->GetUcbScore(c);
    if (score > best_score) {
      best_score = score;
      best_child = this->children[i];
    }
  }

  assert(best_child != nullptr);
  return best_child;
}

Node *Node::FindBestLeafNode() {
  if (this->child_count == 0)
    return this;

  return this->GetBestChild(1.44)->FindBestLeafNode();
}

Node *Node::SearchEnemyMove(int move) {
  this->CreateChildren();

  for(int i = 0; i < this->child_count; i++) {
    if(this->children[i]->enemy_board & (1 << move))
      return this->children[i];
  }
  
  assert(false);
  return nullptr;
}

void Node::CreateChildren() {
  if(this->GetWinner() || this->child_count > 0)
    return;

  for(int pos = 0; pos < 9; pos++) {
    bool p1 = this->ai_board & (1 << pos);
    bool p2 = this->enemy_board & (1 << pos);

    if (!p1 && !p2) {
      Node n(this->arena, !this->is_ai_turn);
      n.parent = this;
      n.ai_board = this->ai_board;
      n.enemy_board = this->enemy_board;

      if(this->is_ai_turn) 
        n.ai_board |= 1 << pos;
      else
        n.enemy_board |= 1 << pos;

      this->arena->push_back(n);

      assert(this->child_count < 9);
      this->children[this->child_count++] = &this->arena->back();
    }
  }
}

void Node::SimulateAndBackpropagate() {
  int eval = this->GetWinner();

  uint16_t saved_ai_board = this->ai_board;
  uint16_t saved_enemy_board = this->enemy_board;
  bool saved_turn = this->is_ai_turn;

  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());

  assert((saved_ai_board & saved_enemy_board) == 0);

  while (!eval) {
    std::vector<int> available_moves;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < 9; pos++) {
      bool p1 = this->ai_board & (1 << pos);
      bool p2 = this->enemy_board & (1 << pos);
      if (!p1 && !p2)
        available_moves.push_back(pos);
    }

    if (available_moves.empty())
      break;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, available_moves.size() - 1);
    int move = available_moves[dis(gen)];

    if (this->is_ai_turn) {
      this->ai_board |= 1 << move;
    } else {
      this->enemy_board |= 1 << move;
    }

    this->is_ai_turn = !this->is_ai_turn;
    eval = this->GetWinner();
  }

  this->ai_board = saved_ai_board;
  this->enemy_board = saved_enemy_board;
  this->is_ai_turn = saved_turn;

  auto curr_node = this;
  while (curr_node != nullptr) {
    curr_node->visit_count++;
    curr_node->eval += curr_node->is_ai_turn ? -eval : eval;
    curr_node = curr_node->parent;
  }
}

Node *Node::CalculateBestMove(size_t iter_count) {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());

  for (size_t i = 0; i < iter_count; i++) {
    Node *leaf = this->FindBestLeafNode();
    leaf->CreateChildren();

    if (leaf->child_count > 0) {
      std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, leaf->child_count - 1);
      leaf = leaf->children[dis(gen)];
    }
    leaf->SimulateAndBackpropagate();
  }
  // The following does not produce the correct behaiviour:

  //  int64_t best_eval = INT64_MIN;
  //  Node *best_node = nullptr;
  //
  //  for (int i = 0; i < this->child_count; i++) {
  //    if (this->children[i]->eval > best_eval) {
  //      best_eval = this->children[i]->eval;
  //      best_node = this->children[i];
  //    }
  //  }

  return this->GetBestChild(0); // This works
}

int Node::GetWinner() {
  for (const uint16_t mask :
      {0b000000111, 0b000111000, 0b111000000, 0b001001001, 0b010010010,
      0b100100100, 0b100010001, 0b001010100}) {
    if ((this->ai_board & mask) == mask) {
      return 1;
    } else if ((this->enemy_board & mask) == mask) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

double Node::GetUcbScore(double c) {
  auto parent = this->parent != nullptr ? this->parent : this;

  if (this->visit_count == 0)
    return DBL_MAX;

  double exploitation = (double)this->eval / this->visit_count;
  double exploration = c * sqrt(log(parent->visit_count) / this->visit_count);

  return exploration + exploitation;
}

Example Bug when not using UCB
The AI (O) just made a move at C2 (instead of blocking):
 A   B   C

   |   | X   1
---|---|---
 O | X | O   2
---|---|---
   |   |     3

Edit
I suppose UCB calculates the average win count, however I am using eval / sim_num not win / sim_num. My interpretation is that the UCB value is normalised, making comparisons between nodes more fair.

You say your original approach failed to block the opponent’s winning moves but then, your example comes with a description of the AI trying to do an invalid move (X in C2 where C2 is already O). Please edit/correct your question.
